# Visio 2007 - Reverse engineer access database fails

Tags: microsoft-access-2007, microsoft-visio-2007

I'm trying to document a number of Access databases using Visio 2007.

The process I'm following is

- create an ODBC connection for the database, pointing to the appropriate file (all files are on my local drive)
- start Visio
- Create a new Database Model Diagram
- From the Database menu pick Reverse Engineer
- pick the data source from the list
- go thru the wizard, selecting all of the tables. (no username or password is needed to open the database in access, so those are left blank)
- when I click finish, I get an error:

  Error! Cannot extract column definition for the table/view 'TABLENAME'.
  The definition is not available or you may not have sufficient privileges.
  Please check with your database administrator.

The db opens fine in Access 2007.

Comment: Why don't you use access to generate the documentation for the database?

Comment: Because I have every other part of the system, including some SQL Servers, documented in Visio.

Answer (score 0):

This was a known bug of visio in 2002, I do not know if it was fixed in later versions. See [here](http://www.developmentnow.com/g/118_2004_1_0_0_468603/Bug-in-Visio.htm) for more info. A workaround seems to be on the last post of the thread:

> A work around is to modify the stored procedure witht he following
>   code after the "as":
>
> ---
>
> --Visio Bug Fix db(2/25/2004)
>
> declare @myTableOwner varchar(64)
>
> select top 1 @myTableOwner=u.name from sysobjects s, sysusers u where
>
> s.uid=u.uid and s.name=@tablename
>
> set @tablename = @myTableOwner + '.' + @tablename

---